# Multiple Data Contexts in router - Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm building a meteor app and on one route I'm adding multiple data context like so -

```
 this.route('orgPage', {
     path: '/org/:title',
     data: {
         orgs: function () {Orgs.findOne(this.params._id)},
         projects: function() {Meteor.subscribe('projects', this.params._id)}
     }
```

The only problem is that when I try to access this data in my templates js file, I can't access the _id or any of the attributes of orgs.

I've tried several approaches, but it always returns undefined. If I use a single data context, it works perfectly. Here is the function that doesn't function properly -

```
    Template.orgPage.events({

  'click #newProject': function(e) {
      $('#npModal').modal();
  },
  'submit #npModal form': function(e, template) {
          e.preventDefault();
    if(!$(e.target).find('[name=newTitle]').val()) {
        var projectTitle = 'Untitled'
    } else {
        var projectTitle = $(e.target).find('[name=newTitle]').val()
    }
    var theid = this._id;
    var newProject = {
        title: projectTitle,
        organization: theid
    }
    Meteor.call('project', newProject, function(error, id) {
          if (error)
            return alert(error.reason);
          $('#npModal').modal('hide');

            $('#npModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
              Router.go('newFields', {});
            })
        }); 
    });
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a return statement. `function () {Orgs.findOne(this.params._id)}` should be `function () {return Orgs.findOne(this.params._id)}`. Further more, `this` inside this function won't refer to what you want, so you can't use `this.params`. And why do you subscribe to a subscription as a data context property? Do it in the `waitOn` function instead.